# Multiple sums from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to add together the totals from each of my tables. I have used an online query generator, however I don't think its right.

```
"SELECT SUM(total) mailTotal,
         SUM(total) extraTotal,
         SUM(total) fbaTotal, 
         SUM(total) gdnTotal,
         SUM(total) ppcTotal,
         SUM(total) smTotal, 
         SUM(total) webTotal
FROM admail,
     extra_charges,
     facebook_adds,
     gdn,
     ppc,
     social_media,
     web
WHERE client = 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should need to try this like below:

```
SELECT SUM(ad.total)  as mailTotal,
       SUM(ex.total)  as extraTotal,
       SUM(fa.total)  as fbaTotal,
       SUM(gdn.total) as gdnTotal,
       SUM(ppc.total) as ppcTotal,
       SUM(sm.total)  as smTotal,
       SUM(w.total)   as webTotal
FROM   admail ad,
       extra_charges ex,
       facebook_adds fa,
       gdn gdn,
       ppc ppc,
       social_media sm,
       web w
WHERE  ad.client = 1
```

Surely This Will Works For You :)

Comment: Try to explain what the OP did wrong and why your code improves/solves OP's problem. Just posting a possibly working piece of code/SQL isn't a good answer.

Comment: When I run $stmt->execute(); i get PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Comment: David, You can execute this query in one by one step. like first get sum of 1st table column, if it works then add another table , and go on.